# Debug.rdl file not found error in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a master report let's say 'Master' which is linked to subreport 'Child'. I can drill through a link provided on Master report to the Child report & vice versa.

The problem is that, I can play with drill through only twice. At the next time, when I click on back button image, which I provided in my Child report, it shows me following error.

```
An error occured during local report processing.
Error in the application.
Could not find file 'C:\...\bin\Debug.rdl'
```

The Debug.rdl file does not exists in my solution as I haven't created it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that the exact copy/pasted error above?  Sure the error isn't a missing "\Debug\something.rdl"?  Have you tried opening the reports in code view (or with notepad), and doing a find for "debug.rdl" to make sure you don't have any unexpected references?  Also perhaps try cleaning the solution (under the build menu).

Comment: Yes. Its a exact error @kyzen, \bin\Debug.rdl. This RDL is not available in my solution, so not possible to open it with notepad. I cleaned & rebuild the solution but no result. This is happening with only one link when I play with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Solved it.

The proble was in the action attribute --> go to report --> specify report I had used one expression which was generating parent report name.

So when I clicked on master report link, it was taking me to child report with the expression generating master report name in the child report.

But when the expression due to some fault or any error was not able generate master report name, the child report was not able to take me to the master report using `<< go Back` link. Rather it was showing me error like **Debug.rdl** file not found.

**Still question remaining is why Debug.rdl ?**